# Erlang module not working after compile while running

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang

I write a simple tcp server module and run it well. When i compile this module while running, the problem is that when the client send anything to server, it receives no response! How can fix it?

```
start(Port) ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{active, once}]),
    spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Listen]).


loop(Listen) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Listen]),
    handler(Socket).



handler(Socket) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
            %io:format("recv ~p~n", [Data]),
            spawn(?MODULE, response, [self(), Data]),
            inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
            handler(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            %io:format("disconnected~n", []),
            gen_tcp:close(Socket);

        {send_msg, Msg} ->
            gen_tcp:send(Socket, lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Msg])) ++ ?END_CHAR),
            handler(Socket)
    end.


response(PID, Data) ->
    [Req|Args] = string:tokens(Data, ?END_CHAR),
    {ReqPID, ReqRef} = spawn_monitor(view, request, [list_to_atom(Req), self(), Args]),
    receive
        {'DOWN', ReqRef, process, ReqPID, {function_clause, _}} -> PID ! {send_msg, invalid_request};
        {'DOWN', ReqRef, process, ReqPID, {{case_clause, _}, _}} -> PID ! {send_msg, bad_args};
        {'DOWN', ReqRef, process, ReqPID, {{badmatch, _}, _}} -> PID ! {send_msg, bad_args};
        Resp -> PID ! {send_msg, Resp}
    end.
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following:

- In your listen options, change `{active,once}` to `{active,false}`. You won't be receiving any messages on your listen socket, and you don't want any accepted sockets to inherit an active setting, as it's better to have them set an active setting when they're actually ready to deal with incoming messages.
- In your `handler/1` function, move the `inet:setopts/2` call to the top, before the `receive`. Also change it to check its return value, like this:

  ```
  ok = inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
  ```

  I suspect you put it under the `{tcp, ...}` message handling clause because technically it's needed only there, but having it at the top is less error-prone. It's also necessary since there's no active setting on the socket the first time `handler/1` is called, given the first change I recommended above.
- In your call to `gen_tcp:send/2`, there is no need to flatten the list returned from `io_lib:format` — it returns an `iolist`, which `gen_tcp:send/2` can handle just fine.